# How can I change the Render Regions background display mode?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I regularly use the handy Render Regions feature of Blender, but I have noticed that no matter what mode you are in before entering *Render* mode, the background mode for the parts of the scene outside the lines is always solid. I want to know if there is a way to change that to *Textured* mode.

Here is an example of what I mean. I am in *Texture* mode, with a render region set up.

[image]

However, when I enter rendered mode the plane on the right loses it's texture, and is now completely solid, obviously being displayed in *Solid* mode.

[image]

Is there a way to change this behavior? And if not, what workarounds are there?

Comment: I just don't get this question. You want to display what the tool is designed **not** to display... why use the tool in the first place?

Comment: @cegaton I want to change what displays **outside** of the render regions border. I want the region rendered, and the outside to be textured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sadly, this appears to be impossible*.**

<sup>*Blender is open source, **you** could always add the feature ;D (I mean isn't that the whole point of open source)</sup>

Answer (score -3):

This is what the API says:

```
use_render_border:
Use a region within the frame size for rendered viewport (when not viewing through the camera)
```

When using this you only see the "render" image inside the `render_border`

That means that it is impossible to do what you are asking, as the RNA automatically changes the viewport display mode outside of the `render_border`.

Comment: Does this make it so whatever mode you entered render mode with will remain visible?

Comment: I don't understand your question...

that mean that if you see the render mode using render_border, only  you show the full image in that  "new" viewport... 

the render border code say:

"Render Border", "Use a region within the frame size for rendered viewport " "(when not viewing through the camera)"

Comment: @yhoyo  I think you don't understand original question. He was asking how to set rendering type outside of render border. It is solid and he wants it textured.

Comment: @JozefCulen thanks, I understand, but that is impossible! because RNA change automatically the outside rendered border viewport in solid mode without texture

Comment: @yhoyo So it is impossible? Because I'd really like to be able to change that. If it sets it to solid mode, can it be changed to set it to something else?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise  why you want to do that?? that is not the render border objetive.   

May be if you check RNA code or Blender builds code you can change this

Comment: In some scenes there are a number of objects in close proximity that can't easily be differentiated without textures being visible, making it harder to navigate quickly from one part of the scene to another.